# Can't import assets from adobe XD into android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, adobe-xd

I made a UI layout using adobe XD and wanted to export it to use in android studio.
I achieved this by using the Export-kit plugin, which conveniently exported all my required assets for one page into a folder.

[Exported assets folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bde82.png)

the [readme.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8n4h.png) then directs me to copy all these assets to the folder for the noactivity project folder for android studio.

after doing so , I still don't get any response.

So, I try it with a basic activity and manually add all the required **XML** codes (activity_main,colours,styles,e.t.c) , but still don't see anything.

I know that the skins exported from xd are in the project folder

[(Copied values in the projects folder)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBHZZ.png)

but I cant seem to view them on android studio.

[Android Studio Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGGVu.png)

any help in this issue will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put those files in the drawables folder inside the res folder, and keep the colors, string into their respective folder in the values folder inside res.

Comment: Yes, I mean the studio can be very specific sometimes and only shows certain folders , and if u tired to keep it somewhere else and then try to use it , it just won't know what your are referring to. Don't forget to accept this answer,if it helps you.